# NSNumberFormatter is acting like my two-year-old

Tags: objective-c

It seems like no matter how many different things I tell NSNumberFormatter, it seems to ignore me. Please help me find the right words for this toddler!

After SO research, Apple documentation, and attempts I am still failing.

My question is: **how can I truncate a NSString to yield a desired number of digits and rounding behavior?**

I am pulling data from an XML API. The number stored in an NSString that I need to format looks like this:

```
29.958662
```

Where there will always be two integer digits, and six decimal digits. I require the formatted number to look like this:

```
29.92
```

Where there are exactly two integer and two decimal digits. In the case of padding zeros the formatted number should look like this:

```
30.00
```

In the first line of pertinent code is where the unformatted number is stored - inspecting altimeterTextString yields @"29.958662"

```
NSString *altimeterTextString = [TBXML textForElement:altimeter];

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSNumber *altimeterValue = [numberFormatter numberFromString:altimeterTextString];
```

Inspecting altimeterValue yields: (double)29.9587

I have tried more iterations of setPositiveFormat:@"00.##", setMinimumFractionDigits, setMaximumFractionDigits, and all the other solutions that seem to work for others on SO, and the same in the documentation for NSNumberFormatter.

There is obviously some formatting going on as the (double) value is being truncated a little, but not what I need.

Any suggestions, besides "welcome to the Hell that is floating point arithmetic"?

Please enlighten me so I can graduate from toddlerhood.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the precision to 100s? Or are you trying to present the value to a user and only need to show that level of precision, while keeping the value for use elsewhere?

Comment: I only need to present that accuracy, ie XX.YY to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong actually. I think you're getting confused by the inspected value and what NSNumberFormatter is for.

Try adding this after the code you posted:

```
NSNumber *altimeterValue = [numberFormatter numberFromString:altimeterTextString];
NSLog(@"%@",[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:altimeterValue]);
```

The output I get is:

> 29.96

What is happening is that it is successfully converting your string into a number (double), and you use NSNumberFormatter to then present that in whatever precision you want to your user.

NSNumberFormatter is particularly for the PRESENTATION of numbers as text, and it does a lovely job of it. The actual conversion, though more powerful than the number conversion methods on NSString, like intValue etc, it's not different in kind.

For the record, you can also convert your string to that same exact double with this line of code:

```
    NSNumber *altimeterValue = @([altimeterTextString doubleValue]);
```

Also, while I was just messing around, if you really want the value to be precisely trimmed as it is in the text, you could do this:

```
NSNumber *trimmedNumber = [numberFormatter numberFromString:[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:altimeterValue]];
```

In that case if you Log your valud of trimmedNumber

```
    NSLog(@"%f", [trimmedNumber doubleValue]);
```

You get: `29.960000`

There's probably a better way to go about it, but in a pinch...

Comment: Excellent, thanks. You were right, I was indeed misinterpreting the purpose of NSNumberFormatter. Thanks for taking the time to explain, thats how you learn things!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this:

```
NSString *altimeterTextString = @"29.958662";
NSString* fStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [altimeterTextString doubleValue]];
NSNumber *altimeterValue = @([fStr doubleValue]);
```

Now if you either inpect or print `altimeterValue` it always has the correct value!

Comment: Thanks, good advice. although I selected a different answer I up voted your comment - useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version in Swift, it should not be a problem to convert it to ObjC:

```
let num = "29.958662"

let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 2

let formattedNumber = formatter.stringFromNumber((num as NSString).doubleValue)

println(formattedNumber)
```

Basically, I create the format, then I use stringFromNumber where I pass double value created from the original string...